# prepend module with ActiveSupport::Concern ? ruby 2+

Tags: ruby, module, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.0, activesupport-concern

```
Module Baz
   def foo
     super
     :baz
   end
end


Class A
   prepend Baz

   def foo
     :bar
   end
end

A.new.foo //works fine
```

now if I transform my module to Concern module, it's not...

```
module BazConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do    
    def foo
      super
      :baz
    end
  end
end
```

So **how can we use prepend with ActiveSupport::Concern ?** with ruby 2+

Comment: because it is not `inlcuded` it is `prepended` which are 2 different hooks. It does not appear that `ActiveSupport::Concern` exposes `prepended` with the block syntax that it exposes `included` with.

Comment: if I just replace included by prepended => `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment *"It does not appear that ActiveSupport::Concern exposes prepended with the block syntax that it exposes included with."* I feel the likely reason for this is due to the fact that prepending the module breaks away from the the purpose of an `ActiveSupport::Concern`. The design pattern for this appears to be to allow for better code organization and step away from the "fat model" concept even if that step is more figurative than literal.

Comment: A Concern is meant to allow for modules that support the Single Responsibility principal but are then included in a class  essentially making them a superclass (they are injected into the inheritance chain above the model). Prepend however actually places the module itself in the inheritance chain by unshifting and everything will pass through it first (generally with a `super` call). If you want your method `foo` to act the same remove `super` from the concern, include the concern in your model and add the `super` call after :bar in A#foo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `prepend` with `ActiveSupport::Concern` (Rails 6.1+)

Rails 6.1 added support of [`prepend`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-prepended) with [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

Please, see the following example:

```rb
module Imposter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # Same as `included`, except only run when prepended.
  prepended do
    
  end
end

class Person
  prepend Imposter
end
```

It is also worth to mention that [`concerning`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module/Concerning.html#method-i-concerning) is also updated:

```
class Person
  concerning :Imposter, prepend: true do

  end
end
```

Sources:

- A link to the corresponding [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/54ecc90d902816b8a96f78c2b2d85d6b8a7df135).
- [Rails allows a module with extend ActiveSupport::Concern to be prepended](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/09/23/prepend-class-methods-for-concerns.html).
- [prepend](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-prepended) and [concerning](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module/Concerning.html#method-i-concerning) docs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a version of `ActiveSupport::Concern` that supports prepending available here: https://gist.github.com/bcardarella/5735987.

I haven't tried it out yet, but I might some day.

(Linked to from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-core/sSk9IEW74Ro)